# Error switching branches in intellij concerning .idea files

Tags: python, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

Currently I'm working on a project via bitbucket with a partner, I was recently trying to go with `git checkout develop` but then an error occured:

```
C:\Users\xx\IdeaProjects\x>git checkout develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .idea/workspace.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .idea/vcs.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I tried to just do it and I tried to solve the problem using "git stash save" but nothing seems to work. On my partners work the error doesn't show up and he's able to move forward with our project but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I hope someone is gonna be able to help me with this, since I don't even know why the error occurs.

Comment: I recommend you adding `.idea/` folder to git ignore because these files are specific for each user.

Comment: @Kyrylo No, they are not. Only `workspace.xml` is specific for each user.

Comment: @yole Did not know that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workspace.xml` should not be added to Git at all. To remove it now, please ask your partner to run `git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml` and then commit this change.

For `vcs.xml`, you can simply delete your own copy of this file before you run the update. It will be replace with a copy from the repository, which will have the same contents.